# jQuery wrapAll contents including text between two tags

Tags: jquery

I try to wrapAll contents between startpost and endpost divs i used nextUntil and wrapAll but the result was wrapping contents without free text between how can i solve that?

```js
$('.startpost').nextUntil('.endpost')
       .wrapAll('<div style="background:red" class="shortpost"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="startpost"></div>
  <a href="http://www.example.com"></a> Hello world!<br>Hello world!
  <div class="endpost"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is expected result each "Hello World!" text to be wrapped in "shortpost" `div` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround that will first wrap any text nodes that are children of the post container in a `<span>` so they will be included in the wrap:

```
$('.post').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        $(this).wrap('<span>');
    }
}).end().find('.startpost')
    .nextUntil('.endpost')
    .wrapAll('<div style="background:red" class="shortpost"></div>');
```

It does leave some empty spans due to whitespace and line breaks but with some adaptation those could be cleaned up if necessary

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2qwkkm73/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use `wrapInner` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/71hj3f7d/))?

```
$('.post').wrapInner('<div style="background:red" class="shortpost"></div>');
```

---

update: if you don't want to include the start & end post elements, try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/71hj3f7d/1/)):

```
$('.post').each(function () {
    var include = false;
    $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        var c = this.className;
        if (/startpost|endpost/.test(c)) {
            include = c === 'startpost';
            return false;
        }
        return include && ( this.nodeType === 3 || this.nodeType === 1 );
    }).wrapAll('<div style="background:red" class="shortpost"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Because you are wrapping whole inner portion of "post", inlcuding whatever is before "startpost" and after "endpost".

Answer (score 2):

As per jQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

> Wraps a newly created tree of objects around the spans. Notice anything in between the spans gets left out like the  (red text) in this example. Even the white space between spans is left out.

What you could/should do is put `"Hello world!<br>Hello world!"` within the `<span>`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <div class="startpost"></div>
  <a href="http://www.example.com"></a> <span>Hello world!<br>Hello world!</span>
  <div class="endpost"></div>
</div>
```

This would get wrapped as expected.

With that said, you can do what you want different way (if you want to exclude startpost, endpost):

```
var inArea = false;
$(".post").contents().each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).hasClass('startpost'))
        inArea = true;
    else if ($(this).hasClass('endpost'))
        inArea = false;
    else if (inArea)
        $(this).wrap('<div style="background:red" class="shortpost"></div>');
});
```

or:

```
var inArea = false;
$(".post").contents().each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    if ($(this).hasClass('startpost'))
        inArea = true;
    if (inArea)
        $(this).wrap('<div style="background:red" class="shortpost"></div>');
    if ($(this).hasClass('endpost'))
        inArea = false;
});
```

if you want to include them.

Comment: These examples wrap every element separately (demos [1](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/71hj3f7d/2/) & [2](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/71hj3f7d/3/))

Comment: would work better inserting the wrap element and doing appends to it instead. Only issue might be loss of any existing events